# How to make protractor tests to work on headless env

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests, integration-testing, end-to-end

first thanks for your time.

A little bit of context:

- I started development of a project which intend to provide a Manual Tests Manager like squash but which can interface with gitlab.
- My stack is based on Spring and Angular, you can find out more [here](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager)

I run my end-to-end tests with protractor, as recommended by angular team.

My tests run fin on my own computer (Macbook Pro 2015), and I tried to automate them using gitlab CI pipeline. For that, i use xvfb to run my tests. And they seems to fail... I can't figure out why and i decide to ask for a little help here =)

My CI job look like this:

```
test_e2e:
    stage: testE2E
    only:
        - master
    before_script:
        - ./gradlew bootJar
        - cp build/libs/*.jar /app.jar
        - start-stop-daemon --exec /usr/bin/mtm --start --background
        - ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
    script:
        - sleep 30 # let daemon start
        - curl http://localhost:8080
        - xvfb-run -a npm run e2e
```

Tips: my processRessources gradle task depends on a task that build frontend
so the front is build before making the jar. The /usr/bin/mtm script launch `java -jar /app.jar`

I don't get why the test fail during the pipeline. I tried to slow down the execution using this [protractor.slow.conf.js](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager/blob/master/src/test/e2e/protractor.slow.conf.js) which use this [snippet](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager/blob/master/src/test/e2e/slow-config.js)

But it still [fails](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager/-/jobs/75429984)... Now I'm crying for help.

The full repository is public so feel free to take a look.

You can also look at the pipeline test execution [here](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager/-/jobs/76033501)

Finally, the protactor test which fail is [here](https://gitlab.com/StonedMoose/manual-testing-manager/blob/master/src/test/e2e/src/app.auth.spec.ts)

Comment: Do your tests runs locally with headless?

Comment: Nop just the no-sandbox switch for chrome. Actually they don't run in headless mode in the docker too. The env is headless but as far as i understand it, the xvfb command emulate a x11 server.

Comment: Pass the `"--headless"` in for chrome options and that should run chrome in headless. As far as xvfb, I don't know enough about that to be useful

Comment: `"--headless"`do the trick.... Thanks !!